# Question on the spacetime outside Earth

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, angular-momentum, metric-tensor

The general metric for a slowly rotating body is $[1]$:

$$ds^{2} = -B(r)dt^{2}+A(r)dr^{2}+r^{2}[d\theta^{2}+sin^{2}\theta(d\phi-\Omega(r,\theta)dt)^{2}]\tag{1}$$

My question is:

**Considering $\Omega = \omega$, a constant. What is form, for $B(r)$ and $A(r)$, in the case of spacetime near Earth?**

---

$[1]$ Slowly Rotating Body in the Scalar-Tensor Theory of Gravitation, V.I. Reizlin (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00898399)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weak field approximation for slowly rotating spheres is

$g_{\rm tt}= 1-{\rm r_s/ r}, \ g_{\rm rr}= -1-{\rm r_s/ r}, \ g_{\rm t \phi}=2 \rm a \ sin^2 \theta / r, \ g_{\rm \theta \theta}=r^2, \ g_{\rm \phi \phi}=r^2 \ sin^2 \theta$

in natural units of $\rm G=M=c=1$ where $\rm a$ is the angular momentum in units of $\rm G M^2/c$.

For the other tensors and equations of motion see [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/22.html). In the strong field like that of black holes the exact solution is the Kerr Newman one, see [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/18.html).

My answer is in the context of general relativity though, I don't know about the Scalar-Tensor theory in your link.